# How does Idris know where to insert Force and Delay?

Tags: functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, idris

According to the [Idris crash course](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#laziness):

> The Idris type checker knows about the `Lazy` type, and inserts conversions where necessary between `Lazy a` and `a`, and vice versa.

For example, `b1 && b2` is converted into `b1 && Delay b2`. What are the specific rules that Idris uses when deciding where to place these implicit conversions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC it's simply based on the unification of the provided type and the expected type. `(&&)` has type `Bool -> Lazy Bool -> Bool`. Unifying the second argument with `y: Bool` converts it to `(delay y)` value. On the other hand, if you'd pass `x : Lazy Bool` as the first argument, it converts to `(force x)`. And this will be done with any values/function with `Lazy a` types.